# Iterating Map List in JSP for Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm sending a List < Map < String, String > > object in a jsp page and I want to create a table with the column names taken from each map's key and values of those columns will be corresponding map's value.

```
 <table>
        <c:forEach var="mList" items="${mapList}">
            <tr>
                <td>test : ${mList.key}</td>
           <td>test : ${mList.value}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Also please let me know how to iterate List < Map < String, String > > object (keeping aside the column names will be each map's key)

Comment: Are maps' keys the same?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in that table? A list of maps sounds like the wrong data structure.

Comment: Basically im fetching response from a service and converted into list of maps now  it is giving multiple rows data so now i want keys which basically will represent column name should appear once as column names in the table and their corresponding value in that column which will be multiple

Comment: @Siddharth it sounds like you need a Map<String, List<String>>, not what you currently have. Can you give a concrete example of the data?

Answer (score 1):

You're treating the `mList` variable as if it's a map entry. However, it is a whole map.
You need to iterate over the entries in that map to access its keys and values:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="map" items="${mapList}">
        <c:forEach var="mapEntry" items="${map}">
            <tr>
                <td>test : ${mapEntry.key}</td>
                <td>test : ${mapEntry.value}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Note that this produces a table of 2 columns with the keys in the first and the values in the second column, not the "column names taken from each map's key" as you need it.

Comment: Thanks. This partially solves the problem can you please make the changes so that all the keys appear just once as the column names in the table.

Comment: @Siddharth no, not unless the maps are ordered. As it stands your data structure and its representation just dont fit together. If you want a table of 2 rows and multiple columns, a simple Map<String, String> suffices. For a table of multiple rows AND multiple columns, use a Map<String, List<String, String>>. Your List<Map<String, String>> can be used like in your example. Can you give an example of the data you want to present?

Comment: https://www.protectedtext.com/31231231 here's the response which consists of two rows. password : 1

Comment: And im converting it into List<Map<String, String>> in which keys are attribute names and values are attribute values

Comment: Even in case if I use Map<String, List<String>> how I will be able to print keys of map as column names(horizontally in a jsp page)?

Comment: @Siddharth given that structure i'd use a list of custom objects,  with each object representing one <attributes> element. I'll try and come up with a solution with what you have, though.

Comment: @Siddharth I dont see a simple way to accomplish what you want with what you have. As it stands, the question of what data structure to use here is really that, a separate question from this one. Please create another one specifically about that topic (but do some research beforehand, please!).